# Regex Assistance for replacing filepaths in markdown documents

Tags: regex, url, replace, markdown, filenames

I migrated my notes from evernote to markdown files with yarle. unfortunately it created me a lot of folders seperatively for the attachments (although I set it up for one folder only).
I moved all attachements to one folder, so the filepath to the attachments in the mardown files needs to be updated.
I think regex would be right for this, but I don't have any knowledge about regex and would be really thankful for help.

Filepaths are as follows:`![[./_attachmentsMove/Coordination_Patterns.resources/CoordinationPattern_Ipsi.MOV]]`

All filepaths are identical `![[./_attachmentsMove/]]` up to this
The second folder varies e.g. `Coordination_Patterns.resources/`.

**I want to delete everything but the filename.extension itself e.g.** `![[CoordinationPattern_Ipsi.MOV]]`.

An example of the other filepaths:
`![[./_attachmentsMove/Jonglieren_(Hände).resources/07 Jonglieren.MOV]]`
(second folder changes, filename changes, I also have .png and .mov).

I use MassReplaceIt (app for mac) which allows me to replace expressions in documents with regex. If someone has a solution using the terminal/commandline, I'll try this as well of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this regexp suffices:

```
(?<=!\[\[)[^\]]+/(?=[^\]/]+]])
```

Replace with empty string.

It should delete the part from the `![[` up to the last `/` before the next `]]`.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the slash or last 2 closing square brackets.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks, fixed. Bad defensive habit)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty thank you so much! That worked -- you saved me so much time!!! I am really thankful!